# Define custom tags in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am a little confused about the function `tag` in shiny. For example if want to define a custom tag; for example, I want to define a FONT tag then I will do something like

`shiny::tag("FONT", varArgs = list("size=2", "color"))`

Now how I will use my defined tag. For example with the predefined tags I can do something like

```
library(shiny)
tags$p("This is my paragraphs")
```

I am looking to use these within a package.

**Updated 2016-10-14**

The following function provided by Geovany (with a slight modification) should work

```
myFont <- function(cont = "", size = 2, color = "#000000") {
  shiny::tag("FONT", varArgs = list(size = size, color = color, cont))
}

myFont("This is my test")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `shiny::tag` function creates the HTML tag and you define it in the arguments. As is in the documentation:

> Named list items become attributes, and unnamed list items become children.

You can create a function to simplifies your work:

```R
myFont <- function(size = 2, color = "#000000") {
  shiny::tag("FONT", varArgs = list(size = size, color = color))
}
```

That function will return something like this:
`<FONT size="2" color="#000000"></FONT>`

This is another example that do something very similar than `tags$p` but also define a class.

```R
myP <- function(cont = "", class = "abc") {
  shiny::tag("p", varArgs = list(class = class, cont))  
}
```

Calling the function as: `myP("hello")` will return: `<p class="abc">hello</p>`

I hope it could help you.

**Updated function to fulfill requirements**

```R
myFont <- function(cont = "", size = 2, color = "#000000") {
  shiny::tag("FONT", varArgs = list(cont, size = size, color = color))
}
```

Comment: Thanks now the documentation make sense; I think `myfont` is missing children. I modified your function similar to `myP` to include `cont` as a children. I edited original post above to include modified function.

Comment: Since I did not know the expected result for the `FONT` tag and didn't add the cont, so that's why I also put the example of `MyP`. Glad to know that it help you to solve your problem.